# Asterisk Manager Interface connection

Tags: php, asterisk

I am a newbie in Asterisk.

I see two ways to connect Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI) in Asterisk:

- AMI over TCP
- AMI over HTTP

How should I use? TCP or HTTP? and why? I have found this [open source PAMI](https://github.com/marcelog/PAMI), this is implement AMI using PHP and seem using TCP connect.

I not found any open source AMI for HTTP connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMI is protocol which require state support, using tcp socket.

Sure you can try do AMI connection via http(using middleware), but it not designed to work like that.

For user via http see ARI interface.

Comment: Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason PAMI isn't available for HTTP is the software is built for commands, as well as receiving events via AMI, which relies on the tcp socket to subscribe to and observe these events. Does your use require observing events, or only sending commands?